# How to output local administrators group membership list into HTML via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell 1 liners that get me the results I'm looking for. Listing out the memberships of the local administrators group.

```
$LocalAdmins = $([ADSI]"WinNT://$Target/Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke('Members')
$Members = $LocalAdmins | foreach { $_.GetType().InvokeMember('ADspath', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null).Replace('WinNT://', '')} | sort -Descending
```

or this:

```
Net localgroup Administrators
```

When I attempt to pipe the results to `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet it seems to just give me the -length property of each object in the pipeline.

Any ideas how to get to get this list to output properly in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

`ConvertTo-Html` takes the properties of the given input object(s) and creates a HTML page to display these properties.

Since your `foreach` outputs just a bunch of strings, it takes the only non-standard property of string, which is `Length`.

If you want to see the string value in the output, too, you can try to add another property, like this

```
| foreach { Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName "Value" -NotePropertyValue "$_"; $_ } | ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: Hi TToni Thanks for that note. Just to clarify for my own understanding. are you saying I should replace my foreach with that statement like that or append it somehow to my existing foreach statement?

Comment: It is meant to be attached to the end of your `$Members = ...` statement.

Comment: Hi,  unfortunately that didn't work. Thanks for the assist though